# Django query ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

Tags: python, django

I'm making a query through Django querysets and it's returning "ValueError: hour must be in 0..23" filtering the dates:

In models.py:

```
class handoff_model(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(batch_def_model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class batch_def_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

In views.py:

```
def ho_open(request):
    date = '2019-07-29'
    all_b = batch_def_model.objects.all()
    for b in all_b:
        if not handoff_model.objects.filter(date=date, batch=b.name).exists():
            batch = handoff_model(batch=b, date=date)
            batch.save()
    handoff_list = handoff_model.objects.filter(date=date,batch__start_time__lt='08:00')
    return handoff_list
```

I already have a few "batch_def_model" objects in my database. Every time you run "ho_open" (changing the hardcoded date) it should create the handoff_models same as "batch_def_model" but for the hardcoded date.

When I set the date as "2019-07-29" it works correctly. Whith date as "2019-07-30" or "2019-07-31" I get the following error:

The full trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 248, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1068, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 412, in _query
    self._post_get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 416, in _post_get_result
    self._rows = self._fetch_row(0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 384, in _fetch_row
    return self._result.fetch_row(size, self._fetch_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 151, in typecast_time
    return datetime.time(int(hour), int(minutes), int(seconds), int((microseconds + '000000')[:6]))
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

I'm not sure why it's not working with those dates because the entire month is working correctly. I've tested by filtering with `date__contains=date` without success.

**EDITED: I realized the rows are being recorded correctly. The issue is when trying to select, in this line:**

```
handoff_list = handoff_model.objects.filter(date=date,batch__start_time__lt='08:00')
```

Do you have any hint?

Comment: What is the value of the `DATE_FORMAT` setting? It looks like you "misconfigured" this.

Comment: I have not set DATE_FORMAT. But anyway, it's that relevant in this example? because this is working fine for all the dates except for 2019-07-30 and 2019-07-31. It don't seems to be a date format issue

Comment: Can you verify what happens if you set a default start_time ? I fear django tries to read the hour from `start_time` to execute request `batch__start_time__lt='08:00'` without verifying `start_time` is not empty

Comment: Hello Sylvain. There's any "batch_def_model" without start_time. All the records have its own "start_time" already set.

Answer (score 0):

Little change in your views.py. This would be my first starting guess. Since your start_time is a TimeField instance (which according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/) a datetime.time instance. Therefore, the right side of the batch__start_time__lt operator should be a datetime.time instance as well.

```py
import datetime
def ho_open(request):
    date = '2019-07-29'
    all_b = batch_def_model.objects.all()
    for b in all_b:
        if not handoff_model.objects.filter(date=date, batch=b.name).exists():
            batch = handoff_model(batch=b, date=date)
            batch.save()
    handoff_list = handoff_model.objects.filter(date=date,batch__start_time__lt=datetime.time(8,0))
    return handoff_list
```

This is my guess without having a chance to look elsewhere in your code. I have limited ways to test it, if it works. If there is an error, please let me know.

Comment: Full trace added to the question body

Comment: @DenisSoto I have not been able to reproduce the problem at my end. Will let you know once I do and if I have a solution.